# insertion sorting function on MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Write an insertion sorting function on MIPS that uses a swap function to perform
the task of sorting an array of integers. The arguments to the function must be an
integer array and its size. Here is the C version of the function:

```
void insertionSort(int * arr, int size) { 
 int i, j; 
 for(i=1;i<size;i++) 
 { 
 j=i; 
 while(j>0 && arr[j]<arr[j-1]) 
 { 
 swap(arr, j, j-1); 
 j--; 
 } 
 } 
} 
void swap(int * arr, int i1, int i2) { 
 int temp=arr[i1]; //Use temp=$t0 
 arr[i1]=i2; 
 arr[i2]=i1; 
}
```

This is my code:

```
    .data
array:  .space 80      # Reserva espaço para 20 inteiros
size:   .word 20       # Tamanho do array
space:  .asciiz " "    # String com um espaço

    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    la      $a0, array       # Carrega endereço base do array
    lw      $a1, size        # Carrega o tamanho do array
    move    $s0, $a1         # Salva o tamanho do array no registrador $s0
    jal     readArray        # Lê o array do usuário
    move    $a1, $s0         # Restaura o tamanho do array do registrador $s0 para $a1
    jal     insertionSort    # Classificar o array
    move    $a1, $s0         # Restaura o tamanho do array do registrador $s0 para $a1
    jal     printArray       # Imprime o array classificado
    li      $v0, 10          # Código de syscall para terminar o programa
    syscall                  # Termina o programa

readArray:
    move    $t1, $zero       # Inicializa o contador
read_loop:
    beq     $t1, $a1, return_read # Retorna se todos os elementos foram lidos
    li      $v0, 5           # Código de syscall para ler um inteiro
    syscall                  # Lê um inteiro
    sll     $t2, $t1, 2      # Calcula o deslocamento
    add     $t3, $a0, $t2    # Calcula o endereço do elemento
    sw      $v0, 0($t3)      # Armazena o inteiro lido no array
    add     $t1, $t1, 1      # Incrementa o contador
    j       read_loop        # Repete o loop
return_read:
    jr      $ra              # Retorna para a chamada

printArray:
    move    $t1, $zero       # Inicializa o contador
print_loop:
    beq     $t1, $a1, return_print # Retorna se todos os elementos foram impressos
    sll     $t2, $t1, 2      # Calcula o deslocamento
    add     $t3, $a0, $t2    # Calcula o endereço do elemento
    lw      $a0, 0($t3)      # Carrega o elemento
    li      $v0, 1           # Código de syscall para imprimir um inteiro
    syscall                  # Imprime o inteiro
    la      $a0, space       # Carrega o endereço da string de espaço
    li      $v0, 4           # Código de syscall para imprimir uma string
    syscall                  # Imprime o espaço
    add     $t1, $t1, 1      # Incrementa o contador
    j       print_loop       # Repete o loop
return_print:
    jr      $ra              # Retorna para a chamada

insertionSort:
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -8     # Reserva espaço na pilha
    sw      $ra, 4($sp)      # Salva $ra na pilha
    sw      $a1, 0($sp)      # Salva $a1 na pilha
    li      $t1, 1           # i = 1
    bge     $t4, $t6, end_while_loop # Se arr[j] >= arr[j - 1], termina o loop

    move    $a1, $t2
    sub     $a2, $t2, 1
    jal     swap

    sub     $t2, $t2, 1         # j--
    j       while_loop

for_loop:
    beq     $t1, $a1, end_for_loop # Se i == size, termina o loop
    move    $t2, $t1                 # j = i

while_loop:
    blez    $t2, end_while_loop # Se j <= 0, termina o loop
    sll     $t3, $t2, 2         # Calcula o deslocamento para arr[j]
    add     $t3, $a0, $t3       # Calcula o endereço de arr[j]
    lw      $t4, 0($t3)         # Carrega arr[j] em $t4

    sll     $t5, $t2, 2         # Calcula o deslocamento para arr[j - 1]
    sub     $t5, $t5, 4
    add     $t5, $a0, $t5       # Calcula o endereço de arr[j - 1]
    lw      $t6, 0($t5)         # Carrega arr[j - 1] em $t6

    bge     $t4, $t6, end_while_loop # Se arr[j] >= arr[j - 1], termina o loop

    move    $a0, $a0
    move    $a1, $t2
    sub     $a2, $t2, 1
    jal     swap

    sub     $t2, $t2, 1         # j--
    j       while_loop

end_while_loop:
    add     $t1, $t1, 1         # i++
    j       for_loop

end_for_loop:
    lw      $ra, 4($sp)         # Restaura $ra
    lw      $a1, 0($sp)         # Restaura $a1
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 8         # Libera espaço na pilha
    jr      $ra                 # Retorna para a cham
swap:
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -4     # Reserva espaço na pilha
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)      # Salva $ra na pilha

    sll     $t0, $a1, 2      # Calcula o deslocamento para arr[i1]
    add     $t0, $a0, $t0    # Calcula o endereço de arr[i1]
    lw      $t1, 0($t0)      # Carrega arr[i1] em $t1

    sll     $t2, $a2, 2      # Calcula o deslocamento para arr[i2]
    add     $t2, $a0, $t2    # Calcula o endereço de arr[i2]
    lw      $t3, 0($t2)      # Carrega arr[i2] em $t3

    sw      $t3, 0($t0)      # arr[i1] = arr[i2]
    sw      $t1, 0($t2)      # arr[i2] = arr[i1]

    lw      $ra, 0($sp)      # Restaura $ra
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 4      # Libera espaço na pilha
    jr      $ra              # Retorna para a chamada
```

Someone can help me?

This is my attempt (for example when I write the numbers from 1 to 20 instead of "sorting" them the output is 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 or if I write the numbers from 20 to 1 the program should return the numbers from 1 to 20).

Comment: That C code swap function is broken.  When we start assembly with broken C code, nothing good comes of it.  Do we need to look further?